# Can we build a R function/Logic to get record IDs by grouping columns

Tags: r

I have below dataset where I want to create a "New_Record_ID" column using the "Current_Record_ID" and "Stores".

For every repeating Current_Record_ID there should only be 2 stores. If Stores exceeds by 2 the record ID should change and increase by +1 to the previous record ID( Expected result).

Sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Stores=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
                 Current_Record_ID=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8))
```

Expected Result:

| Stores | Current_Record_ID | New_Record_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 5 |
| 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 4 | 6 |
| 10 | 4 | 6 |
| 11 | 4 | 7 |
| 12 | 4 | 7 |
| 13 | 4 | 8 |
| 14 | 5 | 9 |
| 15 | 5 | 9 |
| 16 | 6 | 10 |
| 17 | 7 | 11 |
| 18 | 7 | 11 |
| 19 | 7 | 12 |
| 20 | 8 | 13 |

*Also if we have a larger data set of n stores and Currect_Record_ID and we want to fix stores/not to exceed 100 counts. How can we will create the New_record_ID .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be no need for a for loop, but it seems to work well enough, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

counter <- function(id, row) {
  count_up <- case_when(
    id != lag(id) ~ TRUE,
    id == lag(id, n = 2L) & row %% 2 == 0 ~ FALSE,
    id == lag(id, n = 2L) ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE
  )
  
  n <- 1
  
  output <- vector(mode = "integer", length = length(id))
  
  for (i in seq_along(count_up)) {
    if (count_up[i]) {
      n <- n + 1
      } 
    output[i] <- n
  }
  output
}

df |> 
  group_by(Current_Record_ID) |> 
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(New_Record_ID = counter(Current_Record_ID, row)) |> 
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 20 × 3
   Stores Current_Record_ID New_Record_ID
    <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>
 1      1                 1             1
 2      2                 1             1
 3      3                 2             2
 4      4                 3             3
 5      5                 3             3
 6      6                 3             4
 7      7                 4             5
 8      8                 4             5
 9      9                 4             6
10     10                 4             6
11     11                 4             7
12     12                 4             7
13     13                 4             8
14     14                 5             9
15     15                 5             9
16     16                 6            10
17     17                 7            11
18     18                 7            11
19     19                 7            12
20     20                 8            13
```